# Can't retrieve values from the result set when using the INSERT statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

In codeigniter I can't retrieve the values from the `ResultSet` in Microsoft sql server when using the insert statement in a stored procedure.

When I use this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prcTest AS
BEGIN
    select 'test' as test
END
```

I get the value test in test in the `ResultSet`.
But when I use this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prcTest AS 
BEGIN
    insert into test_prc values (2) 
    select 'test' as test
END
```

I don't get anything from the CodeIgniter `ResultSet`. I'm using `foreach($result->result_array() as $row)` to fetch the `ResultSet`.

Comment: `insert into test_prc values (2)`: Does test_prc has only one column???

Comment: Yes it contain only an integer column.

Comment: if it is integer than you can not insert string

Comment: Its an integer value 2 which I insert.select 'test' as test is in the next line. Editing problem , sorry.

Comment: MySQL or MS-SQL Server? Question says MySQL but tagged as sql-server!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience it is MS-SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
insert into test_prc select 'test' as test
```

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE prcTest AS 
BEGIN
    insert into test_prc values (2)
select 'test' as test
END
And the test_prc table consist of only one int column

Comment: if it is integer than you can not insert string

Comment: Its an integer value 2 which I insert.select 'test' as test is in the next line. Editing problem , sorry.